# Integration of a product of Airy function and gaussian function

Tags: indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions, airy-functions

I have been stuck with an integration of the following type
$$\int\frac{2^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}\operatorname{Ai}\left(\frac{2^{1/3}(x-y)}{x^{1/3}}\right)e^{-b\left(k+x\omega\right)^2}\,dx$$
I am not so sure about the limit of the integration.
Is there any closed form possible for the above integral ?

The Airy function is coming from the asymptotic expansion of the Bessel function of first kind and the expansion is valid for $|x-y|\approx |x|^{9/15}$ and I think the limit of the integration has to be calculated obeying the constraint.

Main problem:
I need to perform the following summation,
$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{x}(y) e^{-b\left(k+x\omega\right)^2}$$
where $y\gg 1$.
In such a situation the main contribution of the Bessel function comes from $y\approx x$.
Further in such situation ($y\gg 1$) the peaks of the Bessel functions are very closely spaced which implies the summation can be transformed to an integration over $x$.
Also when $y\approx x\gg 1$ the Bessel function can be written as
$$\frac{2^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}\operatorname{Ai}\left(\frac{2^{1/3}(x-y)}{x^{1/3}}\right)$$
which ultimately gives the required integration.
The Airy function can be written in terms of $K_{1/3}$ and a combination of $J_{1/3}$, $J_{-1/3}$ for when $x-y>0$ and $y-x>0$ respectively.

Comment: Is this simpler than the original problem? You may share the original problem involving the Bessel function.

Comment: I have modified the question by including the original problem.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining a convenient integral representation for the sum by replacing the Bessel functions by an appropriate integral representation and interchanging summation and integration?